# Can I use link stickers when sharing to Stories with Instagram SDK?

Tags: api, sdk, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

I'm looking through the Sharing to Stories [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories) and I can't seem to figure out which stickers are available. Is it really just an image that can only be uploaded to appear above the background?

As far as I can tell, it looks like only images are accepted, but I'm trying to figure out how to apply a link sticker if it's possible.